# background image css not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is the code for the displaying a number of items on a shopping cart image.

The background image is not displaying.

**Style sheet:**

```
div#cart{
    background:url("Cart.gif") no-repeat;

    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
    }
#clickCount{ 
    float:left;
    right:-50px;
    top:-15px;
    position:relative;
    background:lightblue;
    border-radius:80px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

This is the HTML code where I'm using 2 divs one for the display and other for the count:

```
<code>
<div><div id="cart"></div><p id="clickCount">0</p></div>
<div id="click">
  <input type="submit"  onclick="myFunc()" value="Cart"> 
    </input>
</code>
```

Below is the javascript:

```
function myFunc(){
    var val=document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML;    document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML=Number.parseInt(val)+1;
}
```

This is part of my code. The URL works. My HTML is just a regular HTML document with a body etc...

Is there any particular dimensions which I need to consider while choosing an image for this?

Comment: Does "Cart.gif" exist in the same directory as the stylesheet?

Comment: yes it exists in the same directory

Comment: Could you check in the developer tools whether the picture is being recognized with the expected URL and whether it is being loaded?

Comment: the picture was displaying when i chose the inspect element in chrome

Comment: there's a bit of a "code smell" how come you have an extra div surrounding the cart and count?

Comment: That was part of my main program, that will not make any difference as I tried removing it too.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS remove the div text infront of #cart code should then be #cart{

EDIT::
Also your Cart.gif must be 35px x 35px or smaller since you are setting that dimension in the Css. If its larger than this you could only be seeing the top left corner of the image which could be white space

Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/spatacca/sukoww9g/) using a placeholder image for cart

```
#cart{
background:url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=8&txt=cart&w=35&h=35") no-repeat;

display:inline-block;
height:35px;
width:35px;
}
#clickCount{ 
float:left;
right:-50px;
top:-15px;
position:relative;
background:lightblue;
border-radius:80px;
border:1px solid grey;
height:20px;
width:20px;
text-align:center;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It could be because there is nothing in the `div#cart`. Try placing a whitespace character `&nbsp;` inside of it.

```
<div><div id="cart">&nbsp;</div><p id="clickCount">0</p></div>
<div id="click">
  <input type="submit"  onclick="myFunc()" value="Cart" />
</div>
```

Side note: `<input>` tags do not need a closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

I missed giving dimensions for the image.

```
#cart{
    background-image: url("Cart.gif");
      background-size: 35px 40px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check your image if it has 35px*35px dimensions or not,

And if it larger then that of your DIV#cart div dimensions you have to add background positioning properties to CSS.

I have used your code only in below snippet with just google image sprite with positioning properties and it works perfectly fine.

```js
function myFunc(){
    var val=document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML;    document.getElementById("clickCount").innerHTML=Number.parseInt(val)+1;
}
```

```css
div#cart{
    background:url("https://www.google.com/images/nav_logo225.png") no-repeat right -35px ;

    display:inline-block;
    height:35px;
    width:35px;
    }
#clickCount{ 
    float:left;
    right:-50px;
    top:-15px;
    position:relative;
    background:lightblue;
    border-radius:80px;
    border:1px solid grey;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div><div id="cart"></div><p id="clickCount">0</p></div>
<div id="click">
  <input type="submit"  onclick="myFunc()" value="Cart"> 
    </input>
```

Or can check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasimkp/750LcLsd/2/) as well.

Thanks.